# Meteor fails to run after building a meteor app

Tags: cordova, build, meteor

Ok so i have a built a meteor app using the command

```
meteor build bundle --debug --server https://(my app url hosted on meteor)
```

meteor did built a bundle folder with cordova android pack and a tar.gz file.

after building the app , im trying to hit

```
meteor
```

but i get a bunch of errors:

```
While Building the application:
bundle/android/project/cordova/lib/android_sdk_version.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
bundle/android/project/cordova/lib/appinfo.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
bundle/android/project/cordova/lib/build.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
bundle/android/project/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
bundle/android/project/cordova/lib/clean.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
bundle/android/project/cordova/lib/device.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
bundle/android/project/cordova/lib/emulator.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
bundle/android/project/cordova/lib/exec.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
bundle/android/project/cordova/lib/log.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
bundle/android/project/cordova/lib/run.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
bundle/android/project/cordova/lib/spawn.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
bundle/android/project/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/scripts/generate-docs.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
bundle/android/project/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/scripts/run-tests.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
bundle/android/project/assets/www/application/head.html:1: bad formatting in HTML template
bundle/android/project/assets/www/application/index.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
```

viewing inside those js files i see the line of code that makes the error, which is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

note because phonegap and cordova outputted for me an error :"`/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`"

i tried fixing it using `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

of course deleting the bundle folder and hitting "meteor" , does not outputs any error logs and the app is running perfectly.

i guess there is some sort of error with the cordova build...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

according to Slava:

Meteor picks up all javascript files in your project's folder including nested folders. By saving your bundle in the same directory as your project, you just duplicated a lot of files and now Meteor is going to pick them up as "new source files". To avoid this, output your bundles to a separate directory from your project or to a hidden folder that is ignored by Meteor build tool (any folder name starting with a dot).

**EDIT:**
take a look at meteor cordova phonegap integration:

[meteor-cordova-phonegap-integration](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration)

```
meteor build <bundle path> --server <host>:<port>
```

- *folder (example home folder)
- **subfolder (root of project) (example myMeteorApp)

so in order to make things happen try doing consider your on root folder of your app:

`meteor build .bundle --debug --server https://(your app url hosted on meteor)` //will generate hidden direcotrey with the build inside it.

result in:

- *folder (example home folder)
- **subfolder (root of project) (example myMeteorApp)
- ***.bundle (hidden folder inside your root app folder)

or

`meteor build ../bundle --debug --server https://(your app url hosted on meteor)` //will generate a direcotrey with the build inside it .

result in:

- *folder (example home folder)
- **subfolder (root of project) (example myMeteorApp)
- **bundle ( folder inside your home folder)

Comment: Could you please put the exact commands, you did solve the error. I'm a meteor beginner and I have to git reset when ever I face this problem. Thanks :)

Comment: all you need to do is to specify where do you want the bundle directory (or a hidden directorey )

Comment: Shouldn't meteor be changed to avoid this error scenario ?