# Meteor Up deploy failed but app runs fine in development

Tags: javascript, meteor, deployment, meteor-up

I am testing deployment of my first Meteor app, and thought using Meteor Up. After fiddling around much, I managed to run `mup setup` without any errors and everything seems fine.

However, running `mup deploy` fails :

```
$ mup deploy
Building App Bundle Locally
Errors prevented bundling:
While minifying app code:
eval at <anonymous>
(/home/yanick/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.s85ddv++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1),
<anonymous>:1545:18: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (Converter)
at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous>
(/home/yanick/.meteor/packages/standard-minifier-js/.1.2.1.s85ddv++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:28:1),
<anonymous>:1545:18) at js_error (eval at <anonymous>
...
```

The faulty file seems to be a `Converter.js`, but this file is nothing fancy and simply exports some JSON object :

```
import Converter from 'universal-converter';

export default Converter;

export const DEFAULT_UNIT = 'unit';

export const Units = {
  'unit': {
    'type': 'unit',
    'name': 'unit'
  },
  'inch': {
    'type': 'distance',
    'name': 'inch',
    'label': 'in'
  },
  'inch2': {
    'type': 'area',
    'name': 'square inch',
    'label': 'in²'
  },
  'foot': {
    'type': 'distance',
    'name': 'foot',
    'label': 'ft'
  },
  'foot2': {
    'type': 'area',
    'name': 'square foot',
    'label': 'ft²'
  },
  'yard': {
    'type': 'distance',
    'name': 'yard',
    'label': 'yd'
  },
  'yard2': {
    'type': 'area',
    'name': 'square yard',
    'label': 'yd²'
  },
  'cm': {
    'type': 'distance',
    'name': 'centimeter',
    'label': 'cm'
  },
  'm': {
    'type': 'distance',
    'name': 'meter',
    'label': 'm'
  },
  'g': {
    'type': 'mass',
    'name': 'gram',
    'label': 'g'
  },
  'kg': {
    'type': 'mass',
    'name': 'kilogram',
    'label': 'kg'
  },
  'lb' : {
    'type': 'mass',
    'name': 'pound',
    'label': 'lb'
  },
  'oz': {
    'type': 'mass',
    'name': 'once [France]',
    'label': 'oz'
  },
  'liter': {
    'type': 'volume',
    'name': 'liter',
    'label': 'L'
  },
  'gal': {
    'type': 'volume',
    'name': 'gallon [US, liquid]',
    'label': 'Gal'
  },
  'oz_v': {
    'type': 'volume',
    'name': 'ounce [UK, liquid]',
    'label': 'oz'
  }
};
```

Why is `meteor` running fine, but creating a bundle of the application fail?

---

#### Update 1

I have tried refactoring my app directories, [moving the build around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524346/meteor-fails-to-run-after-building-a-meteor-app), nothing changes. This command : `meteor build ../output` (where the path is outside the root folder of my project) fails as described above.

Comment: For some reason, Meteor cannot build your npm package for the client. It seems that `uglifyJS` is trying to minify your ES2015 code and fails to do so. I am not sure what can be done to fix it, but hope that the pointer is useful.

Comment: Seems like this is a known issue. See [#4828](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4828) and [#5517](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5517).

Comment: Right, so because I use `class` inside my `universal-converter` module, the build fail, right?

Comment: Not only that. I think that these are all of the ES2015 features (including object method shorthand notation). You can use a build step before publishing to npm (something along the lines of what's described in those 2 articles: ([1](http://www.hammerlab.org/2015/07/09/bundling-and-distributing-complex-es6-libraries-in-an-es5-world/)), ([2](https://booker.codes/how-to-build-and-publish-es6-npm-modules-today-with-babel/)).

Comment: Yup, fortunately for me, the faulty module was mine, so I added `babel` as dev dep to that module and added the `prepublish` step. It now deploys, but this is not a working solution, but only a hack. If Meteor can run just fine in development, it should build for production. I commented exactly that in the related issue [#4828](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4828).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look [to the related issue on Github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8020).
In this page, @Abernix found a temporary solution:

at root of your project, do theses command line:

```
meteor remove standard-minifier-js

meteor add abernix:standard-minifier-js@1.2.2
```

And then, try again to build.

*WARNING*: As @Abernix said:

> Please don't consider this as a long-term solution (as it will be better if you remain on the official package), but more of a survey to see how their progress is is going. There is still work to be done before it's finished, but I'm curious if it fixes it for any of you. My package is using the 2.7.5 release of the uglify-js harmony branch (which is still not considered stable, but might work for some).

Comment: I forgot about this question (in fact, I am the author of that "related issue on Github!) but, yes, this is the problem. Removing the JS minifier works. I have other issues with the minifier that is not yet resolved, but I did see others confirming that it works.