# Meteor error 'cannot declare let twice' when minifying

Tags: meteor, safari, ios10, minify

When minifying meteor app, **safari on IOS 10** throws the following error

```
SyntaxError: Cannot declare a let variable twice: 't'.
```

I have tried to remove standart-minifier and added abernix:standart-minifier as it was recommended  [on this comment](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8020#issuecomment-289144063) - they work fine on all the other browsers but on safari ios10 it crashes.

Do you have any recommendations?

Thanks a lot

Edit:

I ended up removing minify packages as it was mentioned [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8020) however it definitely not a long-term solution.

Comment: ```abernix:standart-minifier``` Did you actually manage to install this package? I believe it has a typo. Should be standard and not standart

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435209/meteor-up-deploy-failed-but-app-runs-fine-in-development

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor Up deploy failed but app runs fine in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435209/meteor-up-deploy-failed-but-app-runs-fine-in-development)

Comment: sorry for the typo @blueren I have installed it and it also gave me the same error. As you have mentioned it seems like a dupe of the other questions but this issue is about the bug in Safari IOS10 otherwise minifier works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this ios10 safari bug is
[here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/cannot-declare-a-let-variable-twice-e/40956)

Problem is caused by minify default option

```
safari10:false
```

to solve the problem

find these files

**/Users/USER/.meteor/packages/abernix_standard-minifier-js/.2.1.0.1v4h096++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.minifyStdJS.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/abernix_minifier-js/node_modules/uglify-es/lib/minify.js**

and

**/Users/USER/.meteor/packages/abernix_minifier-js/.2.1.0.106pai4++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/uglify-es/lib/minify.js**

then find the following lines and change it as "safari10:true"

```
if (options.mangle) {
        options.mangle = defaults(options.mangle, {
            cache: null,
            eval: false,
            ie8: false,
            keep_classnames: false,
            keep_fnames: false,
            properties: false,
            reserved: [],
            safari10: true,
            toplevel: false,
        }, true);
    }
```